# Django view that redirects to another domain

Tags: python, django, redirect, payment

How to redirect to another domain with python django and pass additional informations?

For example i want to redirect to https://ssl.dotpay.pl/test_payment/ and give additional informations so url will look like this 
https://ssl.dotpay.pl/test_payment/?id=123456&amount=123.00&description=Test
 but I don't want to generate url in my view, just pass the data in json or something like that.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I don't want to generate url in my view, just pass the data in json"?

Comment: this is generated url by what i meant 'https://ssl.dotpay.pl/test_payment/?id=123456&amount={}&description={}'.format(123.00, 'Test')

Comment: ok, so you want your view to redirect to that url, without displaying anything else?

Comment: no, i want my view to redirect to another domain which is not mine but give this domain some arguments.https://ssl.dotpay.pl/s2/login/cloudfs1/magellan_media/common_file/dotpay_technical_manual_for_payments_implementation.pdf what i want to achive is 1.3 'directed version'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is generated url by what i meant 'ssl.dotpay.pl/test_payment/?id=123456&amount={}&description={}'.format(123.00, 'Test')

Be sure to put a protocol before your url (or at least two slashes). 
This way, Django will see it as an absolute path.
From your comment it seems you redirect to `ssl.dotpay.pl` what will be seen as a local path rather than another domain.

This is what I came across. (See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372949/django-redirect-to-another-domain-from-view/50372995#50372995) I put on stackoverflow and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372995/6434747))

So in your case, you can use the following:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        url = 'https://ssl.dotpay.pl/test_payment/'
              '?id=123456&amount={}&description={}'.format(123.00, 'Test')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

You could also use `redirect` from `django.shortcuts` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a functional view, you could probably do something like this in your view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def theview(request):
    # your logic here
    return HttpResponseRedirect(<theURL>)
```