# Django - Redirect to another domain from View

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to redirect from `mydomain.com` to google.com.
There are a couple of answers on stackoverflow that asume the following is working:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('google.com')
```

or

```
return redirect('google.com')
```

But it doesn't it. This just redirects the page to itself and appends the `google.com` part so it comes out like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/google.com
```

What throws a 404 of course..
My view now looks like the following:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('google.com')
```

Can anyone give me insights in what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to prepend it with a protocol, or just `//`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They answers are in some sense correct: you do a redirect. But now the web browser needs to perform the redirect.

Usually paths that are not prepended with two consecutive slashes are assumed to be *local*: so that means it *stays* at the same domain.

In case you want to go to another domain, you need to add a *protocol*, or at least two consecutive slashes (such that the *old* protocol is reused):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('https://google.com')  # use https
```

or:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('//google.com')  # "protocol relative" URL
```

After all you only return a redirect answer to the *browser*. The browser can decide not to follow the redirect (some browsers do), or can interpret it in any way they like (although that means that the browser does not really does what we can expect it to do). We can not force a browser to follow the redirect.

Comment: Aah nice, that really was the issue.. Thanks @WillemVanOnsem!